# who is boss here -- no definite article in front of "boss"?

Tags: definite-article

Example ([Ukraine crisis: Putin shows who is boss in Crimea](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-33985325)):

> RBut it was also about demonstrating who is **boss** here now. Vladimir Putin is spending three days in Crimea with a whole delegation of senior Russian politicians and business figures in tow.

Why do you think there is no definite article in front of the word *boss*? I know some of you will most likely say that the word is being used as a title, but why then is it not capitalized if it's a title? And don't you think that it would sound equally as good if the author had simply said *the boss*?

So,

Question #1:

If it's a title, why is it not capitalized?

Question #2:

Do you think it would sound equally good if the author had simply written *the boss* instead of *boss* without the article?

Comment: When the article is omitted, like in your example, the word 'boss' plays the role of an adjective.  If the definite article is included, then it's a noun.  Either way is fine, I believe.

Comment: I don't believe this is necessarily an adjectival use, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boss can be [used as an adjective](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/boss?s=t) to describe, well, a boss, or master. There is also a slang usage of it that means "first-rate" or "very satisfactory," but that slang isn't really used very often anymore.

As a small bonus, this image seems like it exhibits broken English when it really doesn't:

[image: A valid English sentence, although an awkward one.]